# How to export data into a specific column in a csv file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-csv

What I am trying to do is I import data from a csv file which has UserPrincipalnames and I am taking the names before the @ symbol and then I want to export that data to a specific column in the same CSV file which in this case is o365Users.csv.  I am able to write it out to a text file but I need to know how to export it out to Column G with the header name as SAM

This is my code:

```
$Addys = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\o365Users.csv"
$UPNs = $Addys.UserPrincipalName
    foreach ($UPN in $UPNs) {
    $Name = $UPN.Split("@")[0]
        Write-Output $Name >> c:\scripts\o365Names.txt
 }
```

Comment: If you `Import-CSV`, you get an array of objects, where each object has one field corresponding to each column in the worksheet. You can then do an in-place alteration of the values, in the array (e.g., `$foo[99].ColumnG = 'bar'`), and when you're done, simply `Export-CSV` the array back to the file.

Comment: If you are _adding_ the column, then you'll have to create an array of new objects with the additional field, and `Export-CSV` the new object array instead of the old.

Comment: `Import-Csv -Path $path | % { $_.Name = $_.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[0]; $_ } | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Force`

Answer (score 1):

To **append** a new column with the header `SAM` use `Select-Object` with a calculated property:

```
(Import-Csv 'C:\scripts\o365Users.csv') | 
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='SAM';e={$_.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[0]}}
```

If the new property has to be in a specific position you can't use the wildcard `*` but will have to enumerate **all** headers/columns/properties in the desired order, i.e.

```
(Import-Csv 'C:\scripts\o365Users.csv') | 
    Select-Object -Property ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE,ColF,@{n='SAM';e={$_.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[0]}},ColH
```

replace `Col_` with your real headers.

Due to enclosing the `(Import-Csv)` in parentheses you can export to the same file name (not recommended while still testing) - simply append
`| Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\o365Users.csv' -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to get just the output you are looking for. You would import the current CSV. Create an blank output array and in your loop add each name. Then export the CSV

```
$Addys = Import-Csv "C:\scripts\o365Users.csv"
$UPNs = $Addys.UserPrincipalName

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Output = @()

foreach ($UPN in $UPNs) {
    $Name = $UPN.Split("@")[0]
    $Output.Add($Name) | Out-Null
}

$Output | Export-Csv -Path "C:\scripts\o365Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```